# How to install a module in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I am new to magento and i want to install a custom module in magento.

The steps that i gone through as follows.

1. loged through the admin panel.
2. then selected system -> magento connect -> magento connect manager.
3. in magento connect manager under direct package file upload, i upload the module through upload package file.

The error appear as follows

CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid

Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars

Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x

Invalid stability

Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM

Invalid channel URL

Empty authors section

Empty package contents section

And i also want to know the basic steps to create a module and its structure.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the magento module which you have installed should be from magento connect only. Secondly the extension key must be of magento connect version 2.0. The magento modules downloaded from the magento connect have package.xml file with it. It verifies the currently installed module is from magento connect or not. If not then it gives the error which you are getting currently. If you  want to use the magento module from the sources other than magento connect than you have to include that package.xml file within your magento module.

I hope , I have given you enough information to solve your problem.

Happy Coding :)